# Find which struct field is unequal when using reflect.DeepEqual

Tags: go

How do I find which struct field is different when comparing two structs using `reflect.DeepEqual()`. When I print the struct values then I don't see any difference between the 2 struct values but still the `reflect.DeepEqual()` method returns false

Comment: Please provide an example.

Comment: How are you printing the two struct values? Using `"%#v"` will not, for example, print values pointed to by pointers, so you would have no way of detecting if a two pointer fields point to two values that are equal.

Comment: There was an answer to this question but I dont see it now. There was a useful library link in that answer. Now I couldnt find it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed our by kostix in his (now deleted) answer https://github.com/go-test/deep is very useful. It helped me find my issues in minutes when comparing large structures based on XML/JSON documents.

```
diff := deep.Equal(got, want)
if diff != nil {
    t.Errorf("compare failed: %v", diff)
}
```

With the standard reflect package, I had to more or less implement the diff myself, but in this case it works and the diff shows all the field names up to the values which differ. It makes it really easy to find your issues.

Comment: it can only tell u that got is not equal to want, but not got.x != want.x

Comment: Yes. It tells me whether `got.x != want.x` and if you have 100 fields, it still only tells you that `got.x != want.x` instead of showing all the fields like the `reflect.Equal()` does. Way better. You have to write the diff as shown in my example to see the reduced output.